# Xcode - Colours look different but should be the same

Tags: ios, xcode, hex, uicolor

In my app, I am using the following color: `#3D6D86`

It is set to be a background color on a view controller and also to be the color for the navigation bar on a different view controller. However the problem is that the color appears different. I converted the hex to the correct type of `UIColor` notation for use with swift so I can't see the issue being there either. I will attach some screenshots below to show you what I mean:

[image]
[image]

-----------EDIT-----------

Now when I use this code to try and remove translucency:
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
            UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.24, green:0.43, blue:0.53, alpha:1.0)

I am left with a white gap between the navigation bar and the image which should be below it. Any ideas?

Comment: In IOS 8, the nav bar is transgluent by default. your nav bar add this difference

Comment: The background color of the top screenshot is _#305A73_, the background color of the bottom screenshot is _#598398_.

Comment: Try HSBA: `#3D6D86` is equal to `UIColor(hue: 0.5571, saturation: 0.5448, brightness: 0.5255, alpha: 1.0) // #3D6D86`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the blurring effect on a translucent `UINavigationBar`, the color you set is not exactly how it will be displayed on screen. You can either set your navigation bar's `translucent` property to `NO`:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

... or use [this handy calculator](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/tparry/Miscellaneous/blob/master/UINavigationBar_UIColor_calculator.html) to work out the correct input color to get your desired color on-screen:

Comment: You have almost solved it but got one issue - see updated post

Comment: The white gap you're seeing has always been there, but it was previously *behind* the navigation bar (with a translucent navigation bar, content can extend behind it, but not with an opaque nav bar). I expect you accounted for that when you set up your frames or constraints, and now you need to reposition your image view.

Comment: Yes that was it! Just a bit of re-organizing in the storyboard did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you can set navigationbar's translucent in viewDidLoad :

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];